# Django-filter - group like values with different primary keys in form

Tags: django, django-filter

My goal is to filter a model that refers to plants. Below is an abbreviated version of my model:

```
class Plant(models.Model):

    sku = models.CharField('SKU', max_length=14)
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=50)
    genus = models.ForeignKey(Genus, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['genus', 'name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My related model, Genus, is very basic with just two fields:

```
class Genus(models.Model):
    common = models.CharField('Common Genus', max_length=100)
    latin = models.CharField('Latin Genus', max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['common']
        verbose_name_plural = 'genera'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.common
```

The point here is that an entry for Genus will sometimes have the same value for `latin`. For example Cherry, Peach, and Almond are all *prunus* but each has its own entry.

```
{
    [
        'common': 'Cherry',
        'latin': 'Prunus'
    ],
    [
        'common': 'Almond',
        'latin': 'Prunus'
    ],
    [
        'common': 'Peach',
        'latin': 'Prunus'
    ]
}
```

My problem arises when I use `django-filter` to filter these values. I have a common name filter and a latin name filter. The common name filter is straightforward since the common names will always be unique, but the latin name might be common among many entries.

```
class LatinChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.latin

class LatinFilter(django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter):
    field_class = LatinChoiceField

class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    genus__common = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=Genus.objects.all(), label='Genus')
    latin_q = Genus.objects.all().order_by('latin')
    genus__latin = LatinFilter(queryset=latin_q, label='Latin', field_name='genus')
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['genus__common', 'genus__latin']
```

This provides me with *mostly* what I am after, but the problem is that the `ModelChoiceFilter` will repeat each value for latin names, giving me a `select` input which repeats "Prunus" many times and each one is only related to the primary key of the `Genus` model entry.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/plants/?genus__latin=7
```

Produces:

```
Almond
```

While:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/plants/?genus__latin=4
```

Produces:

```
Cherry
```

**How can I group all the like latin values together either by name or a group of primary keys?**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/plants/?genus__latin='Prunus'
http://127.0.0.1:8000/plants/?genus__latin=7,4,2
```

Should produce:

```
Almond, Cherry, Peach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what you're looking for is really the `AllValuesFilter`. With it, your code would look like this:

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    genus__common = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=Genus.objects.all(), label='Genus')
    genus__latin = AllValuesFilter(label='Latin')
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['genus__common', 'genus__latin']
```

Comment: I assumed it was possibly that simple but found myself in a rabbit hole on the wrong side of town.